# Magento 2 shows var base urls incorrectly

Tags: magento2.4.3.p1

Please forgive me as i am a newbie here and also non-technical but i need someone to help me if possible with a solution to my var base urls in magento 2. The urls are set up correctly in admin panel, if you visit my website and view page source the var base urls shows weird characters\letters\numbers ect. Can anyone please assist?

website: https://safetybox.co.uk/

[image: varbase]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My local magento install shows these URLs in the same way. It is perfectly fine.

- I assume your website loads well and particularly the images are rendered correctly?
- your worry is why are these characters present?

I learnt recently these characters are created by the `\Magento\Framework\Escaper::escapeJs` function; it means your urls are safe to be used by the javascript code that runs on your site.

see this article for more info [devdocs more info](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/security/cross-site-scripting/)

Comment: Thank you Herve...you have put my mind at ease if your magento shows the url's in the same way.

Comment: glad it helped, thanks for confirming you understands the predicament